# i need help to call add() function and also validate function, so first it will validate and than add

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to validate the form on submit and with the same click if form is filled correctly than call the add() function. I'm not an advanced user so kindly keep it simple, and if there are any other ways to do it I would appreciate that.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        function validate() {
            var x = document.forms["myform"]["fnum"].value;
            var y = document.forms["myform"]["snum"].value;
            if( x=="" || x ==null){
                alert("Please Enter the ist Number");
                return false;
            }
            if( y=="" || y== null){
                alert("Please Enter the 2nd Number");
                return false;
            }
        }
        function add(){
            var x = document.forms["myform"]["fnum"].value;
            var y = document.forms["myform"]["snum"].value;
            x=parseInt(x);
            y=parseInt(y);
            var sum = x +y;
            document.write(sum);
        }
        </script>

        <form name="myform" onSubmit="return validate()">
            First Number: <input type="number" name="fnum">
            Second Number : <input type="number" name="snum">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a third function that does this logic, as follows:

```
function submit() {
    if(validate()) {
        add();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then have

```
<form name="myform" onSubmit="return submit()">
...
```

Alternatively, you can have add() call validate() and return false in that case and just have `return add()` in the form submission.